# Is it necessary to observe a significant mean difference in post/pre for the treated group in DiD?

Tags: t-test, causality, difference-in-difference

I have a staggered adoption of a policy across states. I expected the mean of my outcome in post to increase for all treated states, however, I do not observe it consistently. Furthermore, the t-stat of the pre/post means for most states is not significant.

Does this imply that there is no effect?

Comment: Did you expect all treated states to respond to the policy in the same way?

Comment: @ThomasBilach yes. I expected either no effect or a positive one, so the decrease in my outcome in some states is really puzzling.